# Google app engine vs Virtual Hosting? Multiple Symfony app

Tags: google-app-engine, symfony

I want to deploy symfony web pos, I want to  own domain like `webposexample.com`, a demo page like demo `.webposexample.com` and clients pages like `{storename}.webposexample. com`. Every app will need his own mysql database and will use SSL for auth only. And I probably will need to repair bugs, add features on the app.

I'm thinking on Virtual Hosting with apache, but I'm not sure if Google App engine is better for me cause I'm not an experienced server administrator. But I also think Google app engine is more expensive. What do you think?

Comment: why do you think appengine is more expensive? there isnt enough detail about expected usage and such.

Comment: ah okey. But Google charge for app  and vps is only 1 cost